# Finding a date in message body and using it to set a reminder in outlook calendar

Tags: vba, string, date, outlook

Currently I have a macro running on all sent items to check that checks to see if I'm sending the e-mail to a particular customer. If I am, then it checks to see if one of the customer’s requirements for all messages is present which is a 'next update due' if it is not it asks if one is required. See below;

```
Public Sub application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim addrType
Dim addr
Dim recip

For Each recip In Item.Recipients
If recip.Type = olTo Then
    addrType = recip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F")
        If addrType = "EX" Then
            addr = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            addr = recip.Address
        End If
If LCase(addr) = "relevantemail1@outlook.com" Or LCase(addr) = "relevantemail2@outlook.com" Then
    If InStr(1, Item.Body, LCase("next update due"), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        Call errhandler
        Else
        'ask if we've added the date
            prompt$ = "You're sending this to company x and have not added a 'next update due' date, do you need to add one?"
            If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbYes Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
Exit For
    End If
End If
End If
Next

End Sub
```

I am still really getting to grips with the basics of outlook VBA and string functions etc therein. so my question is: can I find the string after the text "next update due:" (ideally I want a formatted date but a string will do for the time being)? Essentially there will always be two delimiters ": " to begin the date and a carriage return to end it. Once I can retrieve it I am able to export the relevant information to an excel document which I will however I am struggling with the initial retrieval of the string/date.

Hopefully you guys can help, more than happy to expand on the above code if needed.

Comment: does the above code work as expected? All sorts of string manipulations can be done with vba. It's tideous and can be confusing but I'm sure with some crafty functions it is doable. I couldnt find the vba msdn page on this but the [vb one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx) is very similar. You'll end up doing something like `Left(Left(Body, Instr(body, "next update due")),instr(Body, vbcrlf) - Instr(body, "next update due"))` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

relative simple regex might be used to extract particular date pattern from body

```
"next update due:(*):"
```

and your result will be captured in those parenthessis

or with specific date formatting:

```
"next update due:*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)*:"
```

if your date is like 10/01/15

Comment: I love using Regular expressions but I think it will be better to give the user the ability to extra anything from the message later on, not just dates and I see the poster doing that in the future. :)

Comment: Ignore my comment I see you have the option for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your code and hopefully it will get you in the right track.

A few observations to help you with the code.

- Always break long code into smaller functions to help you
- Always declare variables
- Always write comments to help you.

Here is the code I hope it helps

```
Public Sub application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim oRecipient As Recipient
    Dim strNextDueDate As String

    For Each oRecipient In Item.Recipients
        If oRecipient.Type = olTo Then

            ' Get the address
            strAddress = GetAddress(oRecipient)

            ' Check the adress for de
            If HasToBeChecked(strAddress) Then
                If InStr(1, Item.Body, LCase("next update due"), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                    'Get the value for the date.
                    strNextDueDate = GetStringBetweenStrings(Item.Body, "next update due:", vbCr)

                    ' ------------------------------------------
                    ' The rest of your code here.....
                    ' ------------------------------------------
                    'Call errhandler
                Else
                    'ask if we've added the date
                    prompt$ = "You're sending this to company x and have not added a 'next update due' date, do you need to add one?"
                    If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbYes Then
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

' Fucntion to check if the address should be chnaged.
' We have it as a separate function so we can add more
' emails if needed.
Function HasToBeChecked(ByVal strAddress As String)

    Dim arrAddresses As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ret As Boolean

    ' Load the array of addresses
    arrAddresses = Array("relevantemail1@outlook.com", "relevantemail2@outlook.com")

    For i = LBound(arrAddresses) To UBound(arrAddresses)
        If LCase$(strAddress) = LCase$(arrAddresses(i)) Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'Return the value
    HasToBeChecked = ret
End Function

' Function to retrive the address from a recipient object
Function GetAddress(ByRef oRecipient As Recipient) As String

    Const strSCHEMA_PROPERTY_TYPE As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F"

    Dim strAddresType As String
    Dim ret As String

    ' Get the address accoring to if it's an excahnge or a regular email
    strAddresType = oRecipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(strSCHEMA_PROPERTY_TYPE)
    If addrType = "EX" Then
        ret = oRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        ret = oRecipient.Address
    End If

    ' Return the value
    GetAddress = ret

End Function

' Function to get he string between teo strings
Function GetStringBetweenStrings(ByVal strToCheck As String, _
                                 ByVal strStart As String, _
                                 ByVal strEnd As String) As String

    Dim lPosStart As Long
    Dim lPostEnd As Long
    Dim ret As String

    lPosStart = InStr(1, strToCheck, strStart)
    If Not lPosStart = 0 Then
        lPosStart = lPosStart + Len(strStart) + 1
        lPostEnd = InStr(lPosStart, strToCheck, strEnd)

        If Not lPostEnd = 0 Then
            ret = Mid$(strToCheck, lPosStart, lPostEnd - lPosStart)
        End If
    End If

    ' Return the value
    GetStringBetweenStrings = ret

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: hiya, I thought I would try out your code quickly and I can see how it's working but when I go to test the string returned by function  "getstringbetweenstrings" it doesn't appear to be doing anything I added in a msgbox after the function is used to obtain the variable strNextDueDate like so (on the following line) MsgBox (strNextDueDate) and the message box returns nothing, I tried a few different delimiters but it doesn't sem to return anything, am I just not getting the msgbox funtion? it's been a long day...

Comment: Its strange, I tested it and it seems to be working as intended for me.